# Kotlin - Find current week start and end date

Tags: kotlin, date, locale, java-time, dayofweek

I have a spring-boot application that will be deployed in multiple countries, and have a requirement to generate the start and end date of the current week. Eg:

```
TimeZone : London
now : 7th March (Tuesday)
startDate : 2023-03-06T00:00:00Z (Monday)
endDate :   2023-03-12T23:59:59Z (Sunday)
```

For doing so, I was using java `locale` with the following code

```
now = ZonedDateTime.now(timeZone)
val dayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(locale).dayOfWeek()
val startDate = now.with(dayOfWeek, 1).with(LocalTime.MIN)
val endDate = now.with(dayOfWeek, 7).with(LocalTime.MAX)
```

Here, the locale will vary with the countries. Eg :

| Country | Locale | Obtained Week start | Expected Start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | de_DE | Monday | Monday |
| Singapore | en-SG | Sunday | Monday |
| Saudi Arabia | ar-SA-u-nu-latn | Saturday | Saturday |

As you can see there is mismatch in Singapore.

Could anyone suggest a better way or library perform this operation.

I checked the first day of the week from this link: [First Day of the Week in Different Countries](http://chartsbin.com/view/41671), where it says that the first day of the week for Singapore is Monday.

Another Evidence: [Singapore Government Website](https://www.mom.gov.sg/employment-practices/hours-of-work-overtime-and-rest-days#:%7E:text=Week%20%E2%80%93%20A%20continuous%20period%20of%207%20days%20starting%20from%20Monday%20and%20ending%20on%20Sunday.:%7E:text=Week%20%E2%80%93%20A%20continuous%20period%20of%207%20days%20starting%20from%20Monday%20and%20ending%20on%20Sunday..)

Comment: Java per default gets its locale data from CLDR, and my observations agrees with you, it thinks that the week begins on Sunday in Singapore.

Comment: Also in Java’s own locale data from before CLDR was introduced (from Java 8, IIRC) Sunday is the first day of the week in Singapore.

Comment: thanks for the reply @OleV.V. I checked the first day of the week from this link: http://chartsbin.com/view/41671 .

Comment: Do you have proof that suggests Java is indeed incorrect? Otherwise I would trust CLDR data more than a map posted by a random user on reddit (looking at the source for your chartsbin).

Comment: See [*Common Locale Data Repository Project (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) in Wikipedia. CLDR is published by The Unicode Consortium, as an authoritative source. Greatly detailed, thoroughly reviewed. Mistakes may still happen, but they are few and far apart now after decades of compilation work. Be aware that cultures *do* change and so the CLDR tracks those changes.

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for replying. I have added another link in the post that mentions the week starts on Monday.

Comment: ***Week** – A continuous period of 7 days starting from Monday and ending on Sunday.* That sounds authoritative alright.

Comment: [Savvy Time](https://savvytime.com/week-number/singapore/2023) says *Weeks are according Singapore calendar rules, **Sunday first day** and weeks are **Sunday to Saturday***. There does not seem to be consensus. If your users in Singapore prefer, you can always use `WeekFields.ISO` to get Monday first.

Comment: The government website seems to suggest that CLDR data is indeed incorrect. Might be worth opening a ticket [in their JIRA project](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR) to have this clarified? Otherwise, it seems like your approach in general is perfectly fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. handling Singapore as an edge may be not a suitable solution in my case. Since I am not sure if there are other countries that have the same discrepancy.

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for the Jira project link. Let me raise a ticket to seek clarification.

Comment: So are you going to redo the work that the Unicode has laid into CLDR over decades, only with fewer errors? I understand your objection and suspicion, but I fail to see a better alternative anywhere.